# Using gcc compile some package statically got an error about libprocps.a

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, static-libraries, ld

```
# g++ -v                                        
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/lto-wrapper
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --enable-default-pie --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none --without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
```

Well, I'm trying to compile my code staitcally with gcc:

```
g++ build/test.o -o build/test -std=c++11 -DCURVE_MNT4 -DNO_PROCPS -I ./src/ -static -lm -lff -lstdc++ -lgmpxx -lgmp -lprocps
```

that code works perfectly fine if you just run the same command without "-static" flag, but because of the project need, we have to compile this code statically, so we have to use "-static" flag and here are some logs:

```
# g++ build/test.o -o build/test -std=c++11 -DCURVE_MNT4 -DNO_PROCPS -I ./src/ -static -lm -lsnark -lff -lstdc++ -lgmpxx -lgmp -lprocps

......
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.a(pwcache.o): In function `pwcache_get_group':
(.text+0x1c8): warning: Using 'getgrgid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.a(pwcache.o): In function `pwcache_get_user':
(.text+0x58): warning: Using 'getpwuid' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.a(readproc.o): In function `sd2proc':
(.text+0x1233): undefined reference to `sd_pid_get_machine_name'
(.text+0x1247): undefined reference to `sd_pid_get_owner_uid'
(.text+0x1296): undefined reference to `sd_pid_get_session'
(.text+0x12b1): undefined reference to `sd_session_get_seat'
(.text+0x12c7): undefined reference to `sd_pid_get_slice'
(.text+0x12dd): undefined reference to `sd_pid_get_unit'
(.text+0x12f3): undefined reference to `sd_pid_get_user_unit'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:22: recipe for target 'build/test' failed
make: *** [build/test] Error 1
```

any idea guys?
I hope there is a way to solve this problem, the "gcc " way or  "ar -r" way or an alternative to “libprocps.a” is fine to me, I just want to know how can I compile successfully with flag "-static", thank you all

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but when using the `g++` frontend program it will automatically link with the `stdc++` library. You don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: It looks like those symbols are in libsystemd, i.e. `-lsystemd`, but I don't have a system to hand with the library to check.

Comment: `ldd libprocps.so` shows it depends on `libsystemd.so.0`, as @Rup said.

Comment: @Rup Is there any static library such as "libsystemd.a" on Ubuntu? How can I install it?

Comment: `packages.ubuntu.com` says no. You will have to dynamically link with `libsystemd`, compile your own static version of `libprocps` without systemd support, or give up on `libprocps`.

Comment: @Botje How can I compile my own static version of libprocps?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/INSTALL.md and passing `--with-systemd=no` to the configure script should do it, I think.

Comment: @Botje You are correct, it working verg good. Thank you for your help. Please kindly attact your answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recompiling [`libprocps`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/blob/master/INSTALL.md) without systemd support (`--with-systemd=no`) got rid of the systemd dependency and allowed @Will_Z to create a fully statically linked binary.